# How to set many reports.rdlc into one report viewer ( In Coding )

Tags: vb.net

I got a problem in my vb Project, as from subject its clear that I have a problem in specifying many reports in one report viewer in one form.
It's difficult to create many forms and adding report viewer in each form.

I have more than 100 reports.rdlc and want to show it in one report viewer by choosing multiple options in combobox or different criterias.

Comment: So what is your question? If anything is difficult, it is not a problem by itself.

Comment: This is a very good question and is reasonably clear.  I don't get the down votes.  All the examples you see doing an internet search seem to tie each rdlc to a new reportviewer form/control.  There isn't much on how to using a single control and dynamically change the report at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the same form window to appear each time you change report in your combobox, just  create a new instance of that form every time you go to generate the .rdlc report.

---

### Button1 Click

When you click this button, it will create two reports. One report will be generated from the method `YourFirstReport()` and the other from `YourSecondReport()`. Both using the same ReportViewer1 control from the same form using a new instance of `rv`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Create instance "rv" of your report viewer form
    Dim rv As New frmReportViewer
    rv.YourFirstReport()

    rv = New frmReportViewer
    rv.YourSecondReport()
End Sub
```

---

### rv.YourFirstReport()

```
Public Sub YourFirstReport()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourProject.YourFirstReportName"
    '...
    'And so on..
End Sub
```

---

### rv.YourSecondReport()

```
Public Sub YourSecondReport()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourProject.YourSecondReportName"
    '...
    'And so on..
End Sub
```

---

Take my example here, the square in red has a button that generates my `frmReportViewer` every time I click on it. The green circles demonstrate my reports that pop up. Both these report utilize the same form.
[image: Multiple reports in 1 form]

Comment: Please I need your more help, can you write the code a little more clear, Just I need to set two different reports.rdlc in one report viewer inside one form.

Comment: @alex I came across a similar problem and iit seems like I can't get through it. Basically the reportViewer has a CHOOSE REPORT selected before i debug. So if WindowsApplication.Report1.rdlc is selected and I run Report2 then it only shows me the headings. But if i run Report1 everything looks fine (headings/data)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single ReportViewer and set his property at runtime:

- path to rldc file: *.LocalReport.ReportPath*
- report datasources: *.LocalReport.DataSources*
- report parameters: *.LocalReport.SetParameters*
- other property: for example *.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages*

Then you can *.RefreshReport()*.

Comment: Can you please write it down in the format that you write in VB.Net coding, I could get something but not clearly !

Answer (score 0):

Just as tezzo said,

```
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report2.rdlc"
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", CType(d1, DataTable)))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("ReportCriteria", criteria))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("FileDate", fileDateString))
    ReportViewer1.Visible = True
    ReportViewer1.DataBind()
```

Changing the localreport reportpath to a different reportname is all you really need.

Comment: where did that d1 variable came from?